# Function return type overloading in Trait

Tags: rust, overloading

I'm writing a function in a trait that either outputs a scalar T or a NdArray `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&T>, I>`. I know that Rust does not support function overloading. I've come across different solutions like outputting a tuple (first element being a scalar, and second being an array). Do you find this solution idiomatic in Rust? Or do you know a better workaround?

My current solution is to create two different traits, one implementing a function outputting a scalar and another function in another trait outputting an array.

I'm looking for a better solution since it would significantly alleviate my codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [associated type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html) in the trait for the output:

```rust
pub trait MyTrait {
    type Output;

    fn execute(&self) -> Self::Output;
}

...
struct MyCompute;

impl MyTrait for MyCompute {
    type Output = u64;

    fn compute(&self) -> Self::Output { ... }
}
```

Comment: It's 100% what I needed. Thanks a lot for your help.