# Multiple return types from same function signature Rust

Tags: rust

I have a function in Rust that takes in two arguments and returns a Result. It is defined below as follows.

```
fn calculate_density(a: String, with_correction: bool) -> Result<u64, String>;
```

The thing is I want to modify my method signature in such a way that the return type for a successful result depends on the argument `with_correction`.

For example id `with_correction` is set to true I send back u64. If false I want to send a String.

I have tried to do this with a tuple where the successful result is a tuple of Options and they are set at run time depending on `with_correction`

```
fn calculate_density(a: String, with_correction: bool) -> Result<(Option<u64>, Option<String>), String>;
```

But this seems like an overkill. Are there better ways to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function return type overloading in Trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70700330/function-return-type-overloading-in-trait)

Comment: Kinda sounds like you actually just want two different functions: `calculate_density(String)->Result<String, String>` and `calculate_density_with_correction(String)->Result<u64, String>`

Comment: I am trying to avoid adding different functions because this behavior is repeated over multiple methods in my project.

Comment: You probably still just wan two different functions. See for example [`as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/?search=as_ref) vs [`as_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/?search=as_mut). Their behavior is also repeaed a lot. (Other than that: If only ever one option of `(Option<…>, Option<…>)`, consider using [`Either`](https://docs.rs/either/latest/either/enum.Either.html), but that's only my 3rd favorite solution.)

Answer (score 6):

If your output depends on a single `bool` input the first thing you should consider is splitting it up into 2 functions:

```rust
fn calculate_density(a: String) -> Result<String, String> {
    // do stuff
}
fn calculate_density_with_correction(a: String) -> Result<u64, String> {
    calculate_density(a).map(|density| density.parse::<u64>().unwrap_or_default())
}
```

If you really, **really** want to have multiple outputs with different types you could use an enum like this:

```rust
enum Output {
    WithCorrection(u64),
    WithoutCorrection(String),
}
fn calculate_density(a: String, with_correction: bool) -> Result<Output, String> {
    // …
    let uncorrected = String::from("uncorrected_value");
    if with_correction {
        let corrected = correct(uncorrected);
        Ok(Output::WithCorrection(corrected))
    } else {
        Ok(Output::WithoutCorrection(uncorrected))
    }
}
```

or if you don't want to write a custom `enum` use `Either`:

```rust
use either::Either;

fn calculate_density(a: String, with_correction: bool) -> Result<Either<u64, String>, String> {
    // …
    let uncorrected = String::from("uncorrected_value");
    if with_correction {
        let corrected = correct(uncorrected);
        Ok(Either::Left(corrected))
    } else {
        Ok(Either::Right(uncorrected))
    }
}
```